# Spark job which writes data frame to hdfs is aborted FileFormatWriter.scala:196

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, file-format

I am trying to store a data frame to HDFS using the following Spark Scala code.

All the columns in the data frame are nullable = true

```
    Intermediate_data_final.coalesce(100).write
    .option("header", value = true)
    .option("compression", "bzip2")
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .csv(path)
```

But I am getting this error :

```
2019-08-08T17:22:21.108+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 979968K->34277K(1014272K)] 1027111K->169140K(1473536K), 0.0759544 secs] [
Times: user=0.61 sys=0.18, real=0.07 secs] 
2019-08-08T17:22:32.032+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1014245K->34301K(840192K)] 1149108K->263054K(1299456K), 0.0540687 secs] [
Times: user=0.49 sys=0.13, real=0.05 secs] 
Job aborted.
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228)
```

Can anybody please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Not the fix for your problem I'm afraid, but if anyone is getting this issue using pyspark then I managed to solve this by separating the query execution and the writing execution into separate commands

```
df.select(foo).filter(bar).map(baz).write.parquet(out_path)
```

Would fail with this error message (for a 3.5GB dataframe) but the below worked fine

```
x = df.select(foo).filter(bar).map(baz)
x.write.parquet(out_path)
```